# Best SQL DB design for temp storage of millions of records

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a database table that collects records at the rate of about 4 records per/sec/device. This table gets pretty big pretty fast. When a device completes its task another process will loop through all the records, perform some operations, combine them into 5 minute chunks, compress them and store them for later use. Then it deletes all the records in that table for that device.

Right now there are nearly 1 million records for several devices. I can loop through them just fine to perform the processing, it appears, but when I try to delete them I time out. Is there a way to delete these records more quickly? Perhaps by turning off object tracking temporarily? Using some lock hint? Would the design be better to simply create a separate table for each device when it begins its task and then just drop it once processing of the data is complete? The timeout is set to 10 minutes. I would really like to get that process to complete within that 10 minute period if possible.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[case_waveform_data] (
[case_id]                INT              NOT NULL,
[channel_index]          INT              NOT NULL,
[seconds_between_points] REAL             NOT NULL,
[last_time_stamp]        DATETIME         NOT NULL,
[value_array]            VARBINARY (8000) NULL,
[first_time_stamp]       DATETIME         NULL
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-caseis-channelindex] ON [dbo].    [case_waveform_data]
(
[case_id] ASC,
[channel_index] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-all-fields] ON [dbo].[case_waveform_data]
(
[case_id] ASC,
[channel_index] ASC,
[last_time_stamp] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [seconds_between_points],
[value_array]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON     PRIMARY]
```

SQL Server 2008+ standard is the DB platform

UPDATE 3/31/2014:

I have started going down a path that seems to be problematic. Is this really all that bad?
I am creating a stored proc that takes a table-value parameter containing the data I want to append and a varchar parameter that contains a unique table name for the device. This stored proc is going to check for the existence of the table and, if it does not exist, create it with a specific structure. Then it will insert the data from the TVP. The problem I see is that I have to use dynamic sql in the SP as there seems to be no way to pass in a table name as a variable to either a CREATE or INSERT. Plus, every article I read on how to do this says not to...

Unfortunately, if I have a single table which is getting all the inserts at a frequency of 4/sec/device, just doing a count on the table for a specific case_id takes 17 minutes even with a clustered index on case_id and channel_index. So trying to delete them takes around 25 - 30 minutes. This also causes locking to occur and therefore the inserts start taking longer and longer which causes the service to get way behind. This even occurs when there is no deleting happening as well.
The described stored proc is designed to reduce the inserts from 4/sec/device to 1/sec/device as well as making it possible to just drop the table when done rather than deleting each record individually. Thoughts?

UPDATE 2 3/31/2014

I am not using cursors or any looping in the way you are thinking. Here is the code I use to loop through the records. This runs at an acceptable speed however:

```
using (SqlConnection liveconn = new SqlConnection(LiveORDataManager.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = liveconn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = channelQueryString;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("channelIndex", channel);
        command.CommandTimeout = 600;
        liveconn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data. 
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new
            {
                //case_id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                channel_index = reader.GetInt32(0),
                last_time_stamp = reader.GetDateTime(1),
                seconds_between_points = reader.GetFloat(2),
                value_array = (byte[])reader.GetSqlBinary(3)
            };
            // Perform processing on item
        }
    }
}
```

The SQL I use to delete is trivial:

```
DELETE FROM case_waveform_data where case_id = @CaseId
```

This line takes 25+ minutes to delete 1 million rows

Sample data (value_array is truncated):

```
case_id channel_index   seconds_between_points  last_time_stamp value_array first_time_stamp
7823    0   0.002   2014-03-31 15:00:40.660 0x1F8B0800000000000400636060    NULL
7823    0   0.002   2014-03-31 15:00:41.673 0x1F8B08000000000004006360646060F80F04201A04F8418C3F4082DBFBA2F29E5 NULL
7823    0   0.002   2014-03-31 15:00:42.690 0x1F8B08000000000004006360646060F80F04201A04F8418C3F4082DBFB    NULL
```

Comment: What about a scheduled job that deleted everyting more than x minutes old, based on the first_time_stamp?

Comment: What about a bit flag to mark the record to be deleted and then do it later when the system is quieter ?

Comment: Enterprise or Standard?  If Enterprise, sounds like a job for partition switching...

Comment: I would prefer not to delete all the data at once in a nightly job if possible. Plus I don't know when the quiet time are in each installation. The data can only be deleted once a case is complete so I delete it by case_id. Case can last for less than an hour or as much as 60 days.

Comment: "...loop through all the records...", "...deleting each record individually..." these are scary descriptions that imply cursors or loops rather than set-based processing. Millions of rows shouldn't generally be a problem and your dynamic partitioning scheme probably isn't the best way to go. I think you should post the SQL of your inserts/updates/deletes, any keys/constraints/indexes on this table, and possibly some sample rows.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting the large amount of data from Table, underneath SQL server marks those to delete and as a background job sql server will actually delete them from page as it gets some idle time. Also unlike Truncate; Delete is Log Enable.

If you would have Enterprise Edition, as other developers have suggested using Partition is the possible approach but you have standard edition.

**Option:1 "Longer, Tedious, Subjective for 100% Performance"**

lets say you keep the single Table approach. you can add a new column "IsProcessed" to indicate what records are already processed. when you insert new data it will have default value 0 so other processes consuming this data will now filter their query using this column as well. after processing you will need additional update on the table to mark those row as IsProcessed=1. Now you can create SQL Server JOB to delete top N rows where Isprocessed=1 and schedule that job as frequently as you can on ideal time slot. "TOP N" because you have to find out by try and error what is the best number for your environment. it may be 100, 1000, 10,000. in my experience if the number is smaller works best. increase the frequency of job execution. lets say "DELETE top 1000 From Table" takes 2 minutes. and you have 4 hours of clean window over night when this table is not being used, you can schedule this job to run every 5 minutes. 3 minutes is just buffer. and hence 12 exec/hour and 1000 rows per execution in 4 hours you will be deleting 48k rows from table. and then over Weekend you have larger window and you will have to catch up with remaining rows.
You can see in this approach lots of back and forth ad lot of minute details and yet it is not sure if this will be last for long for your needs in future. suddenly the input volume of data gets double and all your calculation will fall apart. another down side of this approach is consumer queries of the data will have to now relies on IsProcessed Column value. in your specific case consumer always read all data for a device so Indexing the table doesn't help you instead it will hurt the Insert process performance.
I did personalty experience this solution and last for 2 years in one of our client env.

**Option:2 "Quick, Efficient, Make Sense to me, May Work for You"**

Creating the One Table for device and as you mentioned using a stored procedure to create the table on the fly if does not exist. this is my most recent experience where we have Metadata driven ETL and all the ETL Target objects and API are getting created during run time based on user configuration. yes it is Dynamic SQL but if used wisely and once tested for performance it is not bad. The down side of this approach is debugging during initial phase if something not working. but in your case you know the table structures and it is fixed you are not dealing with daily change in table structure. That is why I think this is more suitable for your situation. Another thing is now you will have to also make sure TempDB is configured properly because using TVP and temp table increases the tempDB usage drastically so you initial and increment space assigned to tempdb, disk on which tempDB is located are two main thing to look at. As I said in Option-1, as the consumer proceses of the data always uses the ALL DATA I do not think you need any extra indexing in place. in fact I would test the performance w/o any index as well. it is like processing All Staging Data.

look at the sample code for this approch. If you feel positive and some doubt on inding or any other aspect of this approach lets us know.

***Prepare the Schema objects***

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('pr_DeviceSpecificInsert','P') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROCEDURE pr_DeviceSpecificInsert
    GO
    IF  EXISTS  (
            SELECT  TOP 1   *
            FROM    sys.table_types
            WHERE   name    = N'udt_DeviceSpecificData'
        )
        DROP TYPE   dbo.udt_DeviceSpecificData
    GO
    CREATE TYPE dbo.udt_DeviceSpecificData
    AS TABLE
    (   
        testDeviceData  sysname NULL
    )
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE pr_DeviceSpecificInsert
    (
        @DeviceData     dbo.udt_DeviceSpecificData READONLY
        ,@DeviceName    NVARCHAR(200)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
            DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX)=N''
                    ,@ParaDef   NVARCHAR(1000)=N''
                    ,@TableName NVARCHAR(200)=ISNULL(@DeviceName,N'')


            --get the UDT data into temp table
            --because we can not use UDT/Table Variable in dynamic SQL
            SELECT * INTO #Temp_DeviceData FROM @DeviceData


            --Drop and Recreate the Table for Device.
            BEGIN
                SET @SQL ='                         
                                if object_id('''+@TableName+''',''u'') IS NOT NULL
                                    drop table dbo.'+@TableName+'
                                CREATE TABLE dbo.'+@TableName+'
                                (
                                    RowID               INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
                                    ,testDeviceData     sysname NULL

                                )
                            '
                PRINT @SQL
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
            END

            --Insert the UDT data in to actual table
            SET @SQL ='
                            Insert INTO '+@TableName+N' (testDeviceData)
                            Select testDeviceData From #Temp_DeviceData
                    '
            PRINT @SQL
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

    COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()  
    END CATCH
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
```

***Execute The sample Code***

```
    DECLARE @DeviceData dbo.udt_DeviceSpecificData
    INSERT @DeviceData (testDeviceData)
                SELECT 'abc'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'xyz'

    EXECUTE dbo.pr_DeviceSpecificInsert
        @DeviceData = @DeviceData, -- udt_DeviceSpecificData
        @DeviceName = N'tbl2' -- nvarchar(200)
```